# Tkinter's OptionMenu callback doesn't work if the list is changed

Tags: python, tkinter, callback, optionmenu

Whenever I change the OptionMenu value, the callback runs smoothly, but my code requires the list (that I use for the OptionMenu) to be updated, when a button is pressed.
When I looked into it, the only answer I could find was to completly erase OptionMenu and then insert each new value through .add_command method.
The simplified code is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

# list_of_files = [] is previously defined 


def Change_selection_OptionMenu(event):
    # Do some changes in the page

var = tk.StringVar(root)
style_optionMenu = ttk.Style()
style_optionMenu.configure('style_option.TMenubutton', background = mycolor, foreground = "white")
option_files = ttk.OptionMenu(root,var,list_of_files[0],*list_of_files, style = 'style_option.TMenubutton', command = Change_selection_OptionMenu )
option_files.config(width = 20)
option_files.grid(row=0,column=0)


tk.Button(master = root, text = "Button", commnad = lambda: button_sabe()).grid()

def button_save():

    #Among other things
    # ...

    var.set('')
    option_files['menu'].delete(0, 'end')

    for choice in list_of_files:
        option_files['menu'].add_command(label=choice,command = tk._setit(var, choice))


root.deiconify()
```

After changing the list of values, the callback doesn't run anymore. I guess the  problem is in the "command" I use for the new type of choices, but I don't know how to deal with it, to simply update the list while still performing the callback when an option is selected.
Anyone can help?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tk._setit` accepts three arguments: the variable, the value and the command that should be executed when selected. So you need to add that third argument:

```
option_files['menu'].add_command(label=choice,command = tk._setit(var, choice, Change_selection_OptionMenu))
```